# Gesture creation for the Leap Motion

Tags: java, api, leap-motion

I was wondering if it is possible to create Leap Motion Gesture sub-classes, such as a "Pinch" class to compliment those already existing, such as the Swipe, Key Tap, Screen Tap, and Circle gestures, preferably using Java.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Gesture class is not designed to be extensible. Instead, you might consider how you want gestures to work in your application model and create your own Gesture classes, some of which may be created from the Leap Motion API gestures.

Comment: Charles Ward : I'm using Unofficial Plugin with Unreal Engine and trying to create own Gestures[Swipe, Move Left Right Up Down] I think these gestures are already there but I'm not sure, don't know how to use it. Can you give some detail to how to use/create these in blueprint.

Comment: I used "EventSwipeGestureDetected" and SwipeOnLeapBasicDirection but no use or I don't know am I using right

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how gestures are implemented in the unofficial plugin or whether they can be accessed from a Blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create your own class for gesture recognition from the data available in the Leap.frame. Feature selection and training a model for gesture recognition can be done in various ways, for example https://github.com/roboleary/LeapTrainer.js you can do something similar.